# Saving and retrieving JSONB columns using SqlKata

Tags: npgsql, sqlkata

I'm manually serializing objects to and from strings and trying to store them in a Postgres database using SqlKata:

```
var obj = new { Id = 3, JsonB = "{a: 5}" };
dbInstance.Query("TableName").InsertAsync(obj);
```

The column `JsonB` is of type `jsonb`. When I attempt to do it this way, I get the following error:

```
Exception data:
Severity: ERROR
SqlState: 42804
MessageText: column "DataField" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text
```

I don't see anywhere in the documentation nor the code to where I can cast types on insert, and am at a loss on how to make it so that I can save JSON strings/objects to the appropriate fields.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. For inserts where json column is present in table switched to use NpgsqlCommand and Npgsql.Json.NET library for serializing objects on the fly. Not SqlKata but working:

```
            Product prod;
            using (NpgsqlCommand command =
            new NpgsqlCommand(@$"INSERT INTO products (json_col) VALUES (@json_col)", connection))
            {                    
                command.Parameters.Add(
                new NpgsqlParameter("json_col", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Value = prod });
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know SqlKata, but indeed you need to tell Npgsql that you're sending a `json` (or `jsonb`) type, since strings are mapped to the PostgreSQL `text` type by default. PostgreSQL is quite type-strict and will not implicitly cast between most types - you will need to find out how to set NpgsqlDbType via SqlKata.